# Pandas Data Frame Queries

Tags: python, pandas

I have Data frame with Keyword column and it contain below values,
"`[{'id': 4379, 'name': 'time travel'}, {'id': 9663, 'name': 'sequel'}, {'id': 11830, 'name': 'hot tub'}, {'id': 179431, 'name': 'duringcreditsstinger'}]`"

I want to create it as new columns in the same data frame with keyword_ID & keyword_name

after manipulation Data frame contain

```
keyword, keyword_ID & Kewword_name
```

Comment: can you elaborate the manipulation please

Comment: what i mean in the Manipulation  result of data frame looks below Keyword Keyword_Id keyword_name
Actual column value 4379 time travel
Actual column value 9663 sequel
Actual column value 11830 hottub
Actual column value 179431 duringcreditsstinger

Comment: yes, if you can post the dataframe and expected dataframe with a brief explaination of the logic that will be great